# Filter log messages by PID or application package in Android

Tags: android, android-logcat

I understand that to filter Android log messages we can use something like

```
adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S
```

But, in my application, I'm using different `TAGS` for different activities and I want to filter all the logs of this application only. What's the best way to do it?

Do I need to specify *all* the tags in the command?

Or using a common tag across the application, the only other alternative?

While looking at log messages in Eclipse, I notice that there is a column named `PID` and another named `Application` (contains name of app package) both of which are (obviously) same for different `Tag` for a given application. That suggests that it should be possible to filter not just by Tag but by pid/package as well.

Comment: Atul,use ActivityManager for getting your application PID then filler on the bases of PID

Comment: ahh, I updated my question before I saw your comment. Is it possible to filter by pid, that's what I want to do.

Comment: @imrankhan how do we filter by pid?

Comment: can you use with grep in pipe?

Comment: @blackbelt: Yes that would work but on the command line I'm just testing what the output looks like but actually I've to pass the arguments of logcat command to a library [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra) so grep in pipe wouldn't work there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a common TAG format as follows.

For `Activities` for example, I have defined a base `Activity` class...

```
public class MyCompanyActivity extends Activity {
    protected final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
    ...
}
```

All `Activities` I create extend that `Activity`, example.

```
public class FishActivity extends MyCompanyActivity {
    ...
}
```

The result is that `FishActivity` will have a `TAG` which is...

```
com.mycompany.myapp.FishActivity
```

All I then need to do is filter the logcat on `com.mycompany.myapp`

Comment: Thanks, this approach looks a clean way of doing it, we wouldn't even need to declare TAG variable in every activity, but just wondering is there any side-effect of using this approach? Since you said "I use..." so I guess this should work fine without any catch, right?

Comment: @AtulGoyal: I can't think of any side effect and have been using this approach since I started with Android development. I've created base classes for `Application`, `Activity`, `Service` and so on. Because of this I never need to manually define a `TAG` and it is always available and reflects the class name with the unique `package.appname` prefix. I even have users help me debug my app by using something like Catlog and filtering on the company name and emailing me the results. It ensures I only get information related to my apps and nothing else that may infringe user privacy for example.

Comment: One more thing, how do you filter the logcat on `com.mycompany.myapp` The logcat command wouldn't work for me when I type `adb logcat com.mycompany.myapp:I *:S` but works for `adb logcat com.mycompany.myapp.FishActivity:I *:S`

Comment: I don't use the adb command line, I use the DDMS perspective in Eclipse (available through Window -> Open Perspective -> Other). I specify a filter to match on `com.mycompany.myapp.*` and it works fine.

Comment: So, there is no way to get it working outside Eclipse? Actually I'm using this library [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to collect crash data when the application crashes so have to pass the parameters of logcat command there. adb logcat command seems to be not much powerful now :(

Comment: Did u try using a regular expression? Like this:

adb logcat com.mycompany.myapp.*:I *:S

The star at the end of myapp is a regular expression, including any characters. I haven't tried it myself but it might be worth giving it a shot.