# Filter logs of given application in cmd not working

Tags: android, logcat

**Note:**
This question is a duplicate of [Filter log messages by PID or application package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658253/filter-log-messages-by-pid-or-application-package-in-android).
But there is no correct answer to that question & it is very very old.

I can't make any changes in the app codebase as suggested in the accepted answer, I can only access the app build.

As per Android Docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#alternativeBuffers
We should be able to filter logs of a given application using the command:
`adb logcat --pid=<pid>`

> --pid= ...   Only print logs from the given PID.

But I am getting an error "unrecognized option" when I enter it in cmd.

Got PID of application using:
`adb shell ps <app-package-name>`

**Note:** Want a solution without using cmd alone, not using Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `adb --pid` command to work , the device/emulator in which you have tired capturing the logcat messages should  atleast be Android 7.0 . Otherwise this command will not work.

if you have device with android 7.0 above , then try this command

```
adb logcat --pid=19816 *:D
```

replace your pid value and * means (any tag) : D meas DEBUG severity log messages

if you have device which is older versions , you can search specific logcat messages based on your package name string or given tag strings like this

```
adb logcat | findstr <PACKAGENAME OR TAGS>
```